# Why can't I add a <br /> with JQuery .html?

Tags: jquery, html, dom

Why does this code work:

```
$('div.error_container').html('<div class="error">No more foo allowed</div>');
```

But this code causes an error:

```
$('div.error_container').html('<div class="error">No more foo allowed<br /></div>');
```

I've tried putting the `<br />` before and after the `</div>` tag, same error.  I've tried changing it from `<br />` to `<br>`.  Chrome always says the following in the inspector:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try breaking it up into a chain:

```
var $div = $('<div class="error"></div>').html('No more foo allowed')
                                         .append('<br />');
$('div.error_container').html($div);
```

Comment: That did it.  I would like to know why, but for now I'm happy that it works.

Comment: Strangely enough, I ran into a similar problem today (with a br tag), and breaking it up into baby steps solved it. I too would like to know why jQuery doesn't like creating/appending elements containing line breaks.

Comment: I get the feeling the other guys are right about the doctype angle.

Comment: Does anyone know why it has this behaviour?

Answer (score 3):

This works perfectly for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $('div.error_container').html('<div class="error">No more foo allowed<br /></div>');
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="error_container">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

in Chrome and Firefox. What version of jQuery are you using?

On a side note `<br />` is XML (including XHTML) not HTML. HTML is `<br>`.

Comment: Read my question again, cletus.  Especially the part where I said "I treid[sic] changing it from <br /> to <br>."

Comment: If above doesn't work (you explicitly stated "try" ;) ), then *try* `<br></br>` instead.

Comment: I tried that one as well.  Interestingly enough, it doesn't seem to matter whether I use <br />, <br> or <br></br>, in all cases the browser reports that it got <br>, and gives me the error.

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that this is actually in a XSL document that's parsed on the server side (don't ask) and sent to the client as html.  It's possible that the conversion from xml to html is the culprit, but breaking it into two parts seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

I tried the following [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) and it works flawlessly in IE, FF, Safari, Opera and Chrome (all of the most recent versions).

So your problem is likely related with the doctype you declared or using an old version of Chrome.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>SO question 2173556</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#foo').html('<div>foo<br>foo</div>');
                $('#bar').html('<div>bar<br/>bar</div>'); // Yes, that's illegal in HTML strict. Just to test :)
            });
        </script>
        <style>

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="foo"></div>
        <div id="bar"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar issue, not sure if it is relevant. I was doing c# mvc for a cms.

So i had some html input from user and i display them using `"@Html.Raw(Modal.Content)"`

Inside the Modal.Content there was a `<br />` and i had issue appending that content into the html using jquery `.html("@Html.Raw(Modal.Content)")`

But in the end the issue was not `<br />`

There is an invisible `\n` so i did `.html("@Html.Raw(Modal.Content).Replace("\n", "")")` and the issue was solved. The `<br>` remained in my content and it work as expected.