# Br not working inside P when using Jquery.html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to assign to `<p>` element a large amount of text, which includes some `<br />` tags inside, as it's html. I am using the .html() method from JQuery, but it wont show the line breaks.

My code:

```
var text = "Hello, this is a pretty <br/> large text with some <br/> line breaks inside"
$('.container').append("<p class='myPClass'><p>");
$('.myPClass').html(text);
```

it does add the text as 'myPClass' html, but it totally ignores the `<br/>` tags.
the result i am getting is:

```
<p class='myPClass'>Hello, this is a pretty large text with some line breaks inside</p>
```

so it would look like:

```
"Hello, this is a pretty large text with some line breaks inside"
```

what i want my result to be:

```
<p class='myPClass'>Hello, this is a pretty <br/> large text with some <br/> line breaks inside</p>
```

so it would look like:

```
"Hello, this is a pretty
large text with some
line breaks inside"
```

what is wrong with my code? or how can i get to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't I add a <br /> with JQuery .html?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173556/why-cant-i-add-a-br-with-jquery-html)

Comment: It works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/RFKgm/

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? I suspect it is a really old version.

Comment: I am not getting any errors, as the guy in that post was. in my case, the `<br/>` tags wont be in the code. I Also tried using `<br>`, `<br \>` and `<br><br\>` as they recommend in the post. I cant append the `<br/>` tag cause i have a really large text and i need it to be in the same `<p>` tag. I tried every answer in that post, and none worked for me. I did my search before posting my question. I just couldnt find a solution.

Comment: I suspect your simplified sample is leaving off an important bit of information, such as what's actually causing the problem. The following fiddle demonstrates one possible cause. http://jsfiddle.net/RFKgm/1/

Comment: @TimBJames i am using the last JQuery version

Comment: @JuanDavidOrozco There are two last jQuery versions, 1.10.x, and 2.0.x

Comment: @JuanDavidOrozco What number?

Comment: @KevinB i am using the 2.0.x version

Comment: Are you looking at the code via "view source", or are you using the developer tools?

Comment: I am using Chrome Developer Tools and Firebug

Comment: What doctype are you using?

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

Comment: @Juanda Can you reproduce it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var text = "Hello, this is a pretty <br/> large text with some <br/> line breaks inside"
$('.container').append("<p class='myPClass'></p>");
$('.myPClass').html(text);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also try the following:

```
var text = "Hello, this is a pretty" + "<br/>" + "large text with some" + "<br/>" + "line   breaks inside"
$('.container').append("<p class='myPClass'><p>");
$('.myPClass').html(text);
```